# Google play Android App version code conflict?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play

This is quite strange situation. I have an android app in the market. Current version is 1.5.1 uploaded on 18th June. Google play is also displaying as last production release. This release has version code 25. yesterday I wanted to do another upload with version code 26 but I only saved as draft.

[image]

[image]

But google play shows me a notification that my release is live in the store[image]

This release had 1.6 as release name but in the store is still 1.5.1. So I wanted to do another release with 1.6. now it tells me that "You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 26". I dont have this release draft also. It doesn't even appear anywhere. it is not also live in the store.

Does anybody have something similar? is it safe to make a new release with code 27 now? because Last release in the market is 25. so I will skip 1 number. will users receive update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's best to go change your version code to 27. Yes, users will receive the update. 
If you can't find it, go to the build.gradle and set the version code and name inside the defaultConfig element

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

You can then upload it. Google only checks the gradle file to manage versions. But the users' client devices have no check. They will update it if the option is checked.

Comment: indeed I am developing with xamarin. there is no gradle in xamarin yet but i guess manifest is the same

Comment: Oh yes, changing in Manifest is the same.

Comment: I think that it is just fine with the version but I wonder why my release draft in between disappeared in the play console.

Comment: That's anyone's guess. My answer is based on an inquiry with the Support team where they said it was not possible to roll back a production version. Since you say it's already there, the best fix is to just update the versionCode and maybe have a message on your description to your users about this. Regards.

Comment: actually version 26 was never in the store uploaded as I wrote. It was saved as draft and discarded but 2nd attempt to upload to play console returned error that i cant upload 26, thats what i didnt understand. I still had 25 live in the store. At the same time , on the left corner there is notificaiton from google that 26 is successfully published. I double check no 26 in the google play store. I saw people have similar problems with google play. obviously some bug in google play console